# I can't use Get Value From Json with JsonPAth parameter in Robot Framework - always have a KeyError

Tags: json, robotframework, jsonpath, keyerror

When I try to use "Get Value From Json"  on a Json with specific JsonPath , I always have KeyError
even web simple example doesn't work for me...

When I try that code :

```
Library           JSONLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Example 
    ${tmp} =  Convert String To JSON    {"foo": {"bar": [1,2,3]}}
    Log to console     tmp: ${tmp} 
    ${values_test}=     Get Value From Json     ${tmp}   $.foo.bar
    Log to console     values_test: ${values_test}
```

I always have this kind of Errors and log :

tmp: {'foo': {'bar': [1, 2, 3]}}
...
Resolving variable '${tmp['$.foo.bar']}' failed: KeyError: '$.foo.bar'

Can somebody Help me please ?

it is really basic example by the way and community always says that it works like that in comments..

Comment: Beats me, this exact code works for me as well. It will be difficult to help you without the possibility to reproduce the problem

Comment: thank you @Jiri Janous , I understand the difficulty :-( ... 
I am going bald from pulling out my hair on that thing 
I tried many things, 
- Json loading from file or creating in robot ;

I don't understand why it try to resolve Resolving variable '${json['$.foo.bar']}' as i try to get specific value from key named $.foo.bar , it seems it doesn't recognize that it is a jsonPATH

The following works :
 ${values_test}=     Get Value From Json     ${tmp}   foo
but not with $.foo.bar

Comment: I found my problem and I am so stupid ...
I used dependancy where i redefined the Get Value From Json keyword  in a bad way ....

Sorry for this post ^^"